# (ASP.NET VB) Referencing a Control from a Variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, controls

I am trying to create a loop process that hides the divider that contains any image controls which doesn't have a valid image URL but I'm having an error that says: **Conversion from string "img1work1" to type 'Integer' is not valid.**
Here's the code:

```
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim imgWork1 As Image
        For i = 1 To 6
            imgWork1 = Me.Controls("img" & i & "work1")
            Dim imageExists As String = Server.MapPath(imgWork1.ImageUrl)
            If Not (File.Exists(imageExists)) Then
                div1Work1.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 1):

`Controls`, which is a `ControlCollection`, expects an Integer as indexer. If you want to get a control by id you have to use `FindControl`.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve it by replacing me.controls with me.findcontrol